# ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "company_groups"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm upgrading rails version to rails6 then the error below occurred.
I don't know where to fix it.
Could anyone have any ideas please share with me...

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "company_groups"
 LINE 1: SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE (company_groups....
 ^

 4:   .control-group
 5:     = f.label :company_id, :class => 'control-label'
 6:     .controls
 7:       = f.collection_select :company_id, Company.user_companies, :id, :name
 8:   .control-group
 9:     = f.label :service_unit_id, :class => 'control-label'
10:     .controls

app/views/admin/service_contracts/_form.html.haml:7
app/views/admin/service_contracts/_form.html.haml:2
app/views/admin/service_contracts/edit.html.haml:4
```

this is _form.html.haml

```
- action = (action_name == "new") ? "create" : "update"
= form_for @service_contract, url: {action: action},
  :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  .control-group
    = f.label :company_id, :class => 'control-label'
    .controls
      = f.collection_select :company_id, Company.user_companies, :id, :name
  .control-group
    = f.label :service_unit_id, :class => 'control-label'
    .controls
      = f.collection_select :service_unit_id, ServiceUnit.all, :id, :name
  .control-group
    = f.label :active, :class => 'control-label'
    .controls
      = f.check_box :active, :class => 'check_box'
  .control-group
    = f.label :in_trial, :class => 'control-label'
    .controls
      = f.check_box :in_trial, :class => 'check_box'
  .control-group
    = f.label :price, :class => 'control-label'
    .controls
      = f.number_field :price, :class => 'number_field'
  .control-group
    = f.label :unlocked_on, :class => 'control-label'
    .controls
      = f.text_field :unlocked_on, type: 'date'
  .control-group
    = f.label :dealer_id, :class => 'control-label'
    .controls
      = f.collection_select :dealer_id, Company.dealers, :id, :name
  .control-group
    = f.label :description, :class => 'control-label'
    .controls
      = f.text_area :description, :class => 'text_area', rows: 4
  .form-actions
    = f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary'
    = link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
      admin_service_contracts_path, :class => 'btn'
```

I fixed another part witch had same error showed the problem clearly so I could figure it out like this below

```
Book.includes(calendar: :company).where("companies.id = ?", company).count
```

fix it to this↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

```
Book.includes(calendar: :company).where("companies.id = ?", company).references(:companies).count
```

thank you.

Comment: According to the stack trace the error is happening on line `7` in the `app/views/admin/service_contracts/_form.html.haml` view. The only part of the line that might trigger such an error could be `Company.user_companies`. The view code itself is not interesting in the context of this question. But how did you define `Company.user_companies`?

Comment: @spickermann .thanks for the comment. I define user_companies like this  ` `code``scope :user_companies, lambda {
    includes(:company_group).
    where("company_groups.has_grant_use = ?", true).references(:company_groups)
  }` in company.rb